# How to make it simple

Tags: vb.net, rename

My code:

```
   Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    PictureBox1.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click
    PictureBox2.Left = "90"
End Sub
```

How can I simply change the name of PictureBox1 and PictureBox2?. Example I just need to change their name like:

```
   Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    I.Enabled = False
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click
    I.Left = "90"
End Sub 
'I change their name to "I"
```

Comment: Do it with the property editor. You cannot change both of them to the same name (why would you want that). If you do it, you also need to change the `handles PictureBox1.Click` to `handles I.Click`. But as a reminder, you cannot change 2 different pictureboxes to 1 name, that wouldn't make any sense

Comment: @duDE : The method name doesn't matter, however the control name and the `Handles` clause does.

Comment: @VisualVincent Only the handles matters :)

Comment: @Icepickle : The control name does too. Both can't be called `I`, and it's the control name that you are to put in the `Handles` clause.

Comment: @VisualVincent If you put it like that it makes more sense than the first statement, as the control name in that case is part of the `handles` clause I took your *control name and handles clause* statement as 2 separate things

Comment: sounds like the c++ #define

Answer (score 0):

You can do that from the properties window. All you need to do is:

- have the object that you want to change its name changed active by clicking on it.
- on the properties window search for (Name) and change it to the name that you want your object to have i.e I but remember that your names should be clear and easy to understand.

Remember that you can not have two different objects the same name in one form you will therefore have to give them different names